# Java: How to find/replace (case insensitive) several substrings with 1 string?

Tags: java, replace

I have the following text

```
http://www.google.com
```

I want to strip out "http://" so the resulting text is

www.google.com

Also, the code should also strip out "https://" in case it's using that.

Thanks

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        String url = "http://www.google.com".replaceAll("(?i)http(s)://", "");
        System.out.print("url: " + url);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current expression will only replace `https://`, not `http://`. You likely wanted to make `(s)` optional, but forgot. `"(?i)http(s)?://"` will do what you want. The parentheses are superfluous on a single character though unless you want to capture it, so `"(?i)https?://"` will do the same, but a bit faster.

Answer (score 2):

```
String url = "http://www.google.com".replaceAll("^(http[s]?://)", "");
```

Try this for your Regex